# Will C# system.Random with 14 characters always be guaranteed to be unique string (hash)

Tags: c#, asp.net, random, hash

I have a utility function in which I want to have as part of my URL querystring .  I need to be sure that it is always unique

```
public static string RandomString(int length)
{
   const string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
   var random = new Random();
   return new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, length)
     .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
}
```

If say I pass in 14 for the length , This generates hash like

```
 YS5bwVTjwEBhFp
 sNi6EfU5rUxI2Z
 sQKhqhklw22vb2
```

If i'm using talking about 20,000 uses a year of this,  Is it safe to say that it should always be unique?

Again

http://:mywebsite.com?id=sQKhqhklw22vb2    is how i would use it

Comment: Of course it's not safe to assume that. `Random` doesn't store up the results of all previous calls for the last year, identify the calling method via reflection, and say, "Oh, it's Miller again, generating a hash. Make sure he gets some fresh ones!"

Comment: `Random` makes no promise of uniqueness.

Comment: For a Globally Unique ID, use... GUID.

Comment: Use a Guid converted to string, it will not be unique but the chances to collide are so small that is considered unique.

Comment: In fact, quite seriously, if `Random` didn't repeat sequences for some period of time, it would be *less random*. If you see "4,0,1,0,4,0,1,0" today, you could be sure you wouldn't see it tomorrow.

Comment: What is the use case for this key?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen   for a mobile app to get a text , click on a link and 1. get the unique hash value so i can look up what their real ID is,  2. them not to be able to get what the next value is    ,  so  if i had a url with id =505346,  i obviously don't want me to click the sms text message and then decide... to try   505347

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to ensure uniqueness is to save the generated values and validate before using that was never used in the past. An alternative is to pre-generate a large number of values, save them in a table, then pick the next available. Variations on this theme are the only way to ensure uniqueness 
if the parameter has no meaning (no semantics).

Another way is to add meaning. Instead of `YS5bwVTjwEBhFp`, `sNi6EfU5rUxI2Z` etc use `0`, `1` etc (an incremental value coming from DB). Of course, you can encode this, eg. by encryption, into a value that has no meaning for user, so the user still see `sNi6EfU5rUxI2Z` but that is base64 encoded encrypted value of `1` or something like that.

And finally, for all practical uses, just using a cryptographic random string (ie. [`RNGCryptoServiceProvider.GetBytes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wb9c8c67(v=vs.110).aspx)) should be more than enough. Not *guaranteed* unique, but hugely improbable to collide.

Comment: How about an operation based on the current timestamp? Like a hash or something? Is that a good idea?

Comment: So this `RNGCryptoServiceProvider.GetBytes`  is much better?    Can you show me an exmple of how to use it?

Comment: @degant Strictly for uniqueness hash of timestamp is probably as unique as anything else. But history is full of successful cryptographic attacks on *predictable* hashes. A random generated string is better.

Comment: I was reading `Guffa` response to similar question    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16616521/how-good-is-this-method-for-generating-random-numbers

Comment: @JeremyMiller better https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19298801/generating-random-string-using-rngcryptoserviceprovider

Comment: @RemusRusanu   -  thoughts on my answer of combining?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if your System.Random is that great,  but you could combine with a much better Cryptopgraphy scheme.    10 of your characters and 40 of better...

Here it is in Linqpad

example :  yours generates `h0UcVayzu2`
the other better one generates `LyR7SUYZ-ZPll36wzGI5kMPamKtyXV_rN0Ax6iZG`

Combined is then 50 characters

```
h0UcVayzu2LyR7SUYZ-ZPll36wzGI5kMPamKtyXV_rN0Ax6iZG
```

Code:

```
void Main()
{

    var x = RandomString(10);
    x.Dump();

    var y = Example.GenerateIdentifier(40);
    y.Dump();

    var z = x + y;

    z.Dump();


}


public static string RandomString(int length)
{
  const string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
  var random = new Random();
  return new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, length)
    .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
}


public class Example {
  static readonly char[] AvailableCharacters = {
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 
    'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 
    'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 
    'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 
    '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '-', '_'
  };

  internal static string GenerateIdentifier(int length) {
    char[] identifier = new char[length];
    byte[] randomData = new byte[length];

    using (RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider()) {
      rng.GetBytes(randomData);
    }

    for (int idx = 0; idx < identifier.Length; idx++) {
      int pos = randomData[idx] % AvailableCharacters.Length;
      identifier[idx] = AvailableCharacters[pos];
    }

    return new string(identifier);
  }
}
```